# Proofs regarding radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Consider $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ with radius of convergence R.

a) Prove that if all $a_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and if infinitely many of them are nonzero, then $R \leq 1$

Proof: Assume $R > 1$, then for $x = 1 < R, \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|$ is absolutely convergent. And if all $a_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and infinitely many are nonzero, then the series diverges. Contradiction.

b) If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n| < 0$, then $R \leq 1$

Proof: From part a), $R > 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} |a_{n}| < + \infty$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n| = 0$ and thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n| = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup |a_n|=\sup|a_n|$. You probably mean $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|$, coded as `\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Also $\limsup |a_n|<0$ is never true. Part (b) would be trivially true. And $\mathbb{I}$, depending on the context can mean many things.

Comment: I see. Do you think my two proofs are correct?

Comment: No. Both the statements and the first proof make little sense.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb I$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant set of integers. Not irrationals.

Comment: Ah, the standard notation for the set of integers is $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: In part b), it ought to be $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} \lvert a_n\rvert > 0$. Then the assertion makes sense and is true.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of your first statement looks fine, although you can argue directly, instead of using contradiction.  Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ must diverge, $R<1$.  As Pp. points out, the statement of part b) doesn't make any sense.